# What are some famous one-liner or two-liner programs and equations?

Tags: algorithms, source-code

I'm experimenting with a new platform and I'm trying to write a program that deals with strings that are no longer than 60 characters and I'd like to populate the data store with some famous or well-known small chunks of code and equations, since programming and math goes along with the theme of my software. The code can be in any language and the equations from any discipline of mathematics, just so long as they're less than a total of 60 characters in length. I suspect people are gonna break out some [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) for this one.

For example,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){printf ("Hi World\n");return 0;}
```

60 characters exactly!

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: Why was brainf**k censored? Can't we be adults and not tell everyone what they can and cannot read? In this context brainf**k is not an obscenity.

Comment: I suspect this question will be closed. Try improve it to be more constructive. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @bigown: This is a good subjective one and is constructive. It's no different than asking for famous quotes. In fact, it's better, because it's asking for famous code/equation "quotes." :-)

Comment: @Macneil:I think the same, but the question is poor, it can be improved.

Comment: @bigown: honestly, I can't really see how this question could be any more constructive. Not to doubt you or so, but very genuily asked, could you suggest an improvement to @BeachRunnerJoe? I actually very much enjoyed the answers and learned a lot from them. I'd love to see this question reopen.

Comment: BTW, that line of C shouldn't compile, as it needs a newline after the preprocessor directive.

Comment: @chaos see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive/24206#24206 and if you don't agree with the policy, take it to some other website

Comment: @Bigown this isn't stackoverflow, its programmers.SE, the site is supposed to be subjective from it's FAQ: _Programmers - Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are interested in subjective discussions on software development._

Comment: @David: Read the link posted.

Answer (score 34):

The classic C string copy routine is known by fewer and fewer people theses days:

```
while (*d++ = *s++);
```

Comment: yes, very famous...to the veterans!

Comment: Indeed, the veterans! I even know some sharp systems people over 30 who have never seen it before.

Comment: While I understand it has "historical" value it's terrible terrible code, so the fact that it's falling in disuse is a good thing =)

Comment: A C veteran would recognize the pattern immediately. It's idiomatic C.

Comment: @Kop - Why is it terrible code? I am not a C veteran and this code seems pretty good to me.

Comment: I suspect he doesn't fancy the readability or lack of safety nets, but when were either of those two things selling points for C?  Tee hee!  It's all about speed baby!

Comment: I remember first seeing this in "Using C", ages ago..(sigh).

Comment: Always thought this was incredibly cool.

Comment: @Chaos: because if you are not familiar with it, you can't tell what it does right away.

Comment: I must say, I agree with @Kop. In just a few chars, it shows signifficant flaws of its standard lib and its semantics. One of the most absurd things is strings being 0-terminated instead of length-prefixed (which is safer and makes determining the length of a string O(1)). The second thing is that C doesn't have actual boolean values (which fixes the `if (alarm = red) launchNukes();`-trap). Dijkstra would consider this code more than harmful. I do agree it is imperative for a C programmer to at least understand this code, but I think it's more important for him to know how to do it better.

Comment: It's elegant in a "C" kind of way as long as the strings are terminated correctly. For a non-C string it can be a terrible death for program or a CPU/host. I've had to debug it because of strings being passed in as Pascal strings (length-byte prefixing the string), or encountering strings that weren't concatenated correctly and having embedded \0 chars. I lean toward it being elegant still, but only in the hands of an experienced C developer. It shouldn't be taught to newbies because they'd shoot their feet off.

Comment: Also anyone doing string copy like this should probably not be programming C in the first place. As other commenters mentioned, this code has no checks for exceeding the string length if its missing the proper termination. Secondly, this code is far from optimal. The strnpy provided by the standard library usually far outperforms this.

Comment: @Schedler, the strncpy function usually far outperforms this?  Can I ask where you saw that?  I ask because it's pretty hard to believe.  The string copy routine that Macneil posted above will result in total of about three assembly instructions.  The whole point of it is it's speed.  The whole point of the strncpy is to provide checks that prevent overflow, so I highly doubt it can outperform this.  Where did you read that?

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe A `strncpy` could copy 32/64-bit words instead of bytes, and resort to copying individual bytes for just the end of the string.

Answer (score 25):

not one line, but I present The World's Last C Bug:

```
    status = GetRadarInfo();
    if (status = 1)
      LaunchNukes();
```

Comment: That's one of those "Oh sh*t!" errors.

Comment: it's `LaunchNukes();`

Comment: if that has been written as: if(GetRadarInfo()=1){...}, we wouldn't get this bug because it doesn't compile. So don't always introduce intermediate variable.

Answer (score 22):

I see Conway's Game of Life in APL floating around a lot:

[image]

An extra bonus is that this will make sure you're handling unicode correctly.

Comment: ha!  that's the first thing I thought of when I saw your code, nice!

Comment: Wow, that's impressive!

Comment: Explanation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9xAKttWgP4

Comment: And I thought Perl looked like line noise.

Comment: @Greg, just wait, APL uses more than the roman and greek alphabets because there weren't enough letters and symbols already; backspace (more properly called "overstrike") is also used because some characters need to be typed on top of other characters. One such was a divide symbol on top of a square, which represented matrix inversion (if unary operator, or multiplication by the inverted matrix if it was used as a binary operator).

Comment: LOL. That's just nasty. Right now I'm thinking that if I cat a binary file to the screen I'd be looking at an APL program. :-) Did they also use `^G` (AKA `BELL`)?

Comment: OMG that's just wrong.

Answer (score 19):

A modified version of a famous Perl one-liner:

```
/^.?$|^(..+?)\1+$/
```

This regular expression matches strings whose length is prime.

The original version is:

```
/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/
```

which matches strings consisting of a prime number of 1s.

Answer (score 14):

Quicksort:

```
qsort []     = []
qsort (x:xs) = qsort (filter (< x) xs) ++ [x] ++ qsort (filter (>= x) xs)
```

If the list is empty, the sorted result is the empty list.

If the list starts with the element x, and the rest of the list is xs, then the sorted result is list consisting of the sorted list consisting of all elements in xs less than x concatenated with the element x concatenated with the sorted list of all elements in xs larger than x.

(or in other words - divide in two piles, all less than x and all larger than x, sort them both and create a list with the less-than pile, the element x, and the larger-than pile).

Beats the understandability of the C version quite easily.

Comment: This is Standard ML? Or Haskell?

Comment: Haskell.  I like the mindset of the language.

Comment: I like the partitioning alternative `qsort (x:xs) = qsort lesser ++ equal ++ qsort greater where (lesser,equal,greater) = part x xs ([],[x],[])`

Comment: Is `part` in the standard library?  Been a while...

Comment: Is there a version of this that uses a random pivot instead of the head of the list? That would make it closer to C.A.R. Hoare's original.

Comment: Hoare says "The item chosen [as pivot element]... should always be that which occupies the highest-addressed locations of the segment which is to be partitioned.  If it is feared that this will have a harmfully non-random result, a randomly chosen item should initially be placed in the highest-addressed locations".  So to be true to Hoare, we should work with the last element, not the first.

Answer (score 13):

1. The [Ackerman function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). The implementation of the Ackermann-Péter version should fit into 60 chars :)
2. This lovely hexadecimal constant: 0x5f3759df. It is the heart of the most WTFing code I've ever seen: the [fast inverse square root](http://www.codemaestro.com/reviews/9).
3. The famous [XOR swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).
4. `question = /(bb|[^b]{2})/`

Comment: +1 for inverse square root

Comment: @Macneil Argh! I was just thinking of that one.

Answer (score 13):

When I first figured out the bash forkbomb, I thought it was really sweet.

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

Comment: Wow, that's just evil!

Comment: Look at all the smilies! You could call this "The Smiley bomb!"

Answer (score 11):

```
print "hello world\n";
```

and its derivations seems to be popular. :-)

Comment: +1: easily the most 'famous' - deserving or not.

Answer (score 10):

Because you mention equations, this one belongs on your list:

```
e^{i\pi}+1=0
```

([Wolfram Alpha rendering](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7Bi%5Cpi%7D%2B1%3D0): [image: e i pi + 1 = 0])

Comment: Yes it does! Good ol' Euler, another good one!

Comment: I remember this as `e^{i/pi} = i^2`

Comment: @Josh K: That's because `i² == -1`, so you can balance the equation by subtracting one from both sides, removing the `+1` and changing the `=0` to `-1` or `i²`

Answer (score 7):

How to detect even numbers:

```
x % 2 == 0
```

Comment: Or `!(x%2)` in sane languages.

Comment: Or `!(x & 1)` in languages without optimizing compiler.

Comment: @Christian, numbers should not be booleans - too easy to make a mistake.

Answer (score 7):

`import this` in Python.

---

EDIT as comments cannot contain line breaks:  For those without a Python interpreter handy, this is the output

```
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Comment: I'm a Python beginner. What would this achieve?

Comment: @Richard: Try writing this in the Python interactive interpreter :).

Comment: This brightened up my Sunday afternoon :)

Comment: @Richard Serious question: If you run this, does it give you a stack overflow?

Answer (score 6):

Not quite 2 lines but I would say this is quite famous:

```
void swap(float* x, float* y)
{
    float t;
    t = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = t;
}
```

Actually some languages can describe it in one line. Lua comes to mind but there are more.

```
x, y = y, x
```

Comment: definitely famous!

Comment: with ints: a ^= b ^= a ^= b;

Comment: I'm just curious how is this implemented? does it create a temporary table (y, x), then assign x the 1st element and y the 2nd element?

Comment: Also I'm wondering how often do people swap values in real life programing.

Comment: @tactoth - Swapping is commonly used for implementing strongly exception safe assignment in C++.

Comment: @Kaz Dragon such as?

Comment: @tactoth X& X::operator=(X other) { swap(*this, other); return *this; }

Comment: @Kaz: your first comment is right, the second one... the standard swap implementation *relies* on operator=, and thus is usually not exception safe. And would recurse to death in your example.

Comment: @peterchen - Not so.  The exception safety comes from std::swap on basic types being nothrow and as long as member swaps are written to use only swap, not assignment, they too will be nothrow. Hence exceptions are only thrown at the copy, before side-effects.  Naturally, swap will be overloaded for your type and only applies swaps to the members, not the whole, so there's no recursion.  The technique is called the copy-swap idiom.  See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap and http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/ for more information about it.

Comment: @Kaz: I just meant that non-overloaded std::swap isn't nothrow, and if you combine your operator= implementation with the swap implementation you given (and which is the default), you run in circles. An exception-safe swap isn't necessarily available. (I've seen the misconception that swap "automagically" makes your assignment exception safe more than once)

Comment: @peterchen: Obviously, I wasn't using the non-overloaded swap, because that would be broken.  It's a common enough idiom; I thought that would be understood.

Comment: No problem, it was just the unfortunate combination of two code snippets that triggered my reply.

Comment: Which language is that and why doesn't it support `void swap(float* x, float* y){float t; t = *x; *x = *y; *y = t;}`?

Answer (score 6):

My favorite lambda calculus example is the Y combinator:

```
Y = λf.(λx.f (x x)) (λx.f (x x))
```

Answer (score 6):

From an exercise in *K&R,* here is a function that will return how many bits are set in the number given. At 58 characters:

```
int bits(int n){int b=0;while(n){n=n&(n-1);b++;}return b;}
```

It takes time proportional to the number of bits set. The "ah ha" part here is that

```
n = n & (n - 1)
```

Removes the rightmost set bit from `n`.

Comment: Awesome, nice K&R reference!

Answer (score 6):

#### Unix Roulette (DANGER!)

Courtesy of Bigown's answer in the joke thread (and the comment):

```
[ $[ $RANDOM % 6 ] == 0 ] && rm -rf /* || echo Click #Roulette
```

(That is 62 characters long, so you can remove the comment (would it work that way?) or some non-essential spaces.)

Comment: Please mark this as dangerous.

Comment: I use zsh and it doesn't work unless s/==/-eq/ :-)

Answer (score 6):

#### Recursive Pascal's Triangle in One Line (Haskell)

```
  r n=take(n+1)$iterate(\a->zipWith(+)(0:a)$a++[0])[1]
```

Fifty-two characters, add spaces to taste. Courtesy of "Ephemient" in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242073/code-golf-generate-pascals-triangle/1242174#1242174).

I thought this was a better example than the cryptic but brief solutions in **J** and **K** (though I'm no Haskell user, yet).

Answer (score 5):

**Infinite Fibonacci Sequence (Haskell)**

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Comment: Why not `fibs = 0 : scanl (+) 0 fibs`?

Answer (score 4):

```
DO 10 I=1.3
```

This is one of the most expensive bugs in history.  This Fortran statement assigns the float value of 1.3 to the variable named `DO10I`.

The correct code - the header of the loop repeating statements until the statement labeled 10 and the loop variable `I` accepting values 1, 2, 3:

```
DO 10 I=1,3
```

Comment: Why is it an expensive bug?

Comment: This bug was in a subroutine that calculated orbital trajectories for a 1961 Mercury space flight.  However, it was caught and fixed before launch, and was therefore *not* a costly bug.  There was a similar bug on a Mariner mission that *did* cause failure of the mission, though.  (source: _Expert C Programming_, pages 31-32.)

Answer (score 4):

[Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device):

```
void send(short *to, short *from, int count)
{
    int n = (count +7 ) / 8;

    switch (count % 8) {
    case 0: do {    *to = *from++;
    case 7:         *to = *from++;
    case 6:         *to = *from++;
    case 5:         *to = *from++;
    case 4:         *to = *from++;
    case 3:         *to = *from++;
    case 2:         *to = *from++;
    case 1:         *to = *from++;
        } while(--n > 0);
    }
}
```

Tom Duff unrolled a memory-mapped port write into one of the most bizarre C constructs the world has seen.

Comment: It doesn't fit into 60 characters, but it def is cool. I remember getting chills seeing his name scroll past in the credits to some Pixar movie.

Answer (score 2):

```
val (minors, adults) = people.partition(_.age < 18)
```

The above line of Scala code partitions `people` (a list of `Person`s) into two lists based on their respective ages.

It takes the following much of code to do the same thing in Java:

```
List<Person> minors = new ArrayList<Person>();
List<Person> adults = new ArrayList<Person>();
for(Person p : people) {
  if(p.age < 18) {
    minors.add(p);
  } else {
    adults.add(p);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swapping the values of two variables without using a third variable. This is one of the first things in programming that I was told and thought "Hmm... that's cool"

```
int a,b; 
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
b=a+b;
```

Comment: I know you can do this using `XOR`s, but this was my bit of nostalgia for today :)

Comment: XOR has no problem with overflow. Does this?

Answer (score 2):

[Black magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) from John Carmack

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    y  = number;
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       // evil floating point bit level hacking
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );               // what the ****?
    y  = * ( float * ) &i;
    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 1st iteration
//  y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 2nd iteration, this can be removed

    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**The largest number that can be represented by 8 Byte (Python)**

```
print '\n'.join("%i Byte = %i Bit = largest number: %i" % (j, j*8, 256**j-1) for j in (1 << i for i in xrange(8)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything to do with Hello World comes to mind. You could go with different variations if you plan on storing multiple languages.

For something more non-trivial, there's [Fibbonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Fibonacci).

Comment: Fibbonacci, nice one!  Here's the code...
if (k < 2) return k;else return fib(k-1) + fib(k-2);

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe: You might want to combine that with the conditional operator ;)

Comment: yes indeed!  return (k < 2) ? k : fib(k-1) + fib(k-2);

Answer (score 1):

1. **Conditional operator** :

   minVal = (a < b) ? a : b;
2. **Switch case**
3. [for-each loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) [Java]

Comment: Actually, conditional operator is the correct name. An operator is ternary if it takes three arguments.

Comment: @back2dos - Indeed, both C# and JavaScript call this the conditional operator.

Comment: @back2dos - The ?: operator *does* take three arguments, which is why it is called the ternary operator. This has been the correct terminology from C onwards. (apparently starting from BCPL, according to Wikipedia...)

Comment: @grkvlt: I never said it doesn't take three arguments. It's just that you wouldn't call `!` the unary operator or `+` the binary operator. It's simply not exact.

Comment: @back2dos - Since there's only *one* ternary operator (our friend `?:` in C, Java et al.) the definite article is appropriate in this case, and is the way it has always been referred to. However there are *multiple* unary and binary operators, so `!` must be described as *a* unary operator, and so on...

Comment: @grkvlt: I disagree both with your argument (if you had one apple and two carrots on the table, you wouldn't refer to the apple as "the fruit") as with your claim ( please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A )

Comment: @back2dos - I think this is our problem - I *would* refer to the apple as "the fruit" in that situation, but I think we're arguing grammar, not programming language syntax, and you are correct that `?:` is the conditional operator ;)

Comment: I don't know of any other infix ternary operators.  Examples would be interesting, please! :D

Answer (score 1):

This [Quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) from the [Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/Q/quine.html) in C:

```
char*f="char*f=%c%s%c;main(){printf(f,34,f,34,10);}%c";main(){printf(f,34,f,34,10);}
```

There is also a LISP version there, too, but you can find *many* others floating around, in pretty much any language you could imaging...

Answer (score 1):

euler's identity which links the most beautiful numbers in math universe: 1, 0, e, i and π : **e^i(π) + 1 = 0**

Answer (score 1):

I had a good one and I wrote it down in the margin.

Comment: Nice one Fermat

Answer (score 1):

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
   while(b>0)
   {
      int t = a%b;
      a=b;
      b=t;
   }
   return a;
}
```

Probably not famous, but one of my favorites. To most it's not immediately apparent why it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit over 60 characters but it really depends on variable naming (so I'm including it!)

let readLines (rdr : StreamReader) =

     
          seq { while not rdr.EndOfStream do

              
 yield rdr.ReadLine()}

Nice little function to read a file into a sequence line by line in F#.

Answer (score 1):

For cheap, fast, easy approximation of rotation around the "x" axis:

```
d = 0.0001;
y = y + z * d;
z = z - Y * d;
```

It's an approximation, but not one that you'd ever notice the error on

Answer (score 1):

[Infinite Fibonacci Sequence](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17355/what-are-some-famous-one-liner-or-two-liner-programs-and-equations/17749#17749) in Scala:

```
val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = 0 #:: 1 #:: { for((x, y) <- fibs.zip(fibs.tail)) 
                                           yield x + y }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reverse of a string recursively**

```
 if ( str.length() <= 1)  { return str; // stopping case } 
 else { return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0); // recursion   }
```

Comment: But in 60 characters or less! (He did say "two-liner", so does the limit apply only per line?)

Comment: Oooh My answer wont qualify here!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just updated the question to specify a total of 60 characters or less, but it's a great code snippet.  Question, should you be using block comments in there?

Answer (score 0):

Not famous, but a hideous way of calculating the square root of *n*, with the result as *n*.

```
for(double r=1;r!=n;n=r==(r=0.5*(r+(n<0?-n:n)/r))?r:n);
```

And yes, negative number handling is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I like the newer feature of C# to return not null value:

```
var notnull = userInputName ?? "Captain NEMO";
```

And their lambdas are pretty sweet also:

```
Func<int, int, int> addfn = (a, b) => a + b;
Func<int, int> addtwofn = (a) => addfn(a, 2);
var result = addtwofn(5); // returns 7
```